# How to show members of a group with their photo on a page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I cannot find how to show the photos and names of the members of a group on a page.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Modern SharePoint as you've tagged sharepoint-online.

Modern Pages don't yet have a web part to show the members of a group, it currently only exists for an individual person record.

Now this is a bit of a jury-rigged 'WD40 and duct tape' solution but what you could do is thus:

1. Set up some code (could be JavaScript in a browser, a C# Azure solution, or a Powershell CSOM script) that gets a list of all the group members (the specific code used would differ depending on whether you're talking about an Azure AD, SharePoint or Unified group)
2. The code then extracts all the relevant info you need for that account (picture URL, job title, whatever)
3. The code would then dump this information into a SharePoint list on your site
4. Now you can add a web part that shows an embedded view of that list

Obviously remember to set up the code that's doing the work so it runs regularly, or if possible on an event trigger for when the groups membership is updated (unsure if this functionality exists - I'm really more of an OOTB developer).

Comment: I found that on every page on the right site the nummer of members of the group is shown. When I click on it the members are shown. So I think I don't need a web part it is already there. Anyway thanks.